# After I set session to be stored in db there is a delay before it is registered. Node/Express/express-session,

Tags: node.js, session, express, sequelize.js, express-session

After log in I want to redirict to /makeitem, which requires a session to open. This works, but after the log in form is submitted I get my error message and I have to refresh to enter the /makeitem. This worked perfectly fine before I started using *connect-session-sequelize*. The cookie gets stored in db.Sessions right away so that part works.

Why is this happening? Do I have to check for the session somewhere else in my middleware?
How can I make it redirect without any hazzle?
Am I missing something obvious?

Thank you, and please don't just link to docs, I've been looking at docs all day and they make my fairly new programmer brain hurt. I need som love and education.

SERVER.JS

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var _ = require('underscore');
var app = express();

var db = require('./db.js');

// initalize sequelize with session store
var SequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store);


// if heroku use that, else use 3000
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cookieParser());

// Track logins with express session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'Magic mike',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new SequelizeStore({
        db: db.sequelize
    })
}));

// Make userId available in templates
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.session.userId;
    next();
});
....
```

ROUTES/INDEX.JS

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var _ = require('underscore');
var mid = require('../middleware/');
var db = require('../db.js');

.....

// POST /login
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'email', 'password');

    if (req.body.email && req.body.password) {
        db.user.authenticate(body).then(function(user) {
            req.session.userId = user.id;
            return res.redirect('makeitem');
        });
    } else {
        var err = new Error('All fields required.');
        err.status = 400;
        err.message = 'All fields required.';
        console.log(err.message);
        res.send(err.message);
    }

});
.....
    // GET /makeitem
router.get('/makeitem', mid.requiresLogin, function(req, res, next) {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'description', 'amount', 'purchased');

    return res.render('makeitem.pug');
});
....
```

MIDDLEWARE/INDEX.JS

```
 function loggedOut(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session && req.session.userId) {
        return res.redirect('/makeitem');
    } else {
        return next();
    }
}

function requiresLogin(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session && req.session.userId) {
        return next();
    } else {
        var err = new Error('You must be logged in to view this page');
        err.status = 401;
        return next(err);
    }
}

module.exports.loggedOut = loggedOut;
module.exports.requiresLogin = requiresLogin;
```

My relevant dependencies are:

- "express": "^4.14.0"
- "express-session": "^1.14.1"
- "sequelize": "^3.5.1"
- "connect-session-sequelize": "^3.1.0"
- "sequelize": "^3.5.1"
- "sqlite3": "^3.1.4"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds very similar to the issue :

[Race Condition When Used With Passport](https://github.com/mweibel/connect-session-sequelize/issues/39)

Your best way of solving this would be :

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'email', 'password');

    if (req.body.email && req.body.password) {
        db.user.authenticate(body).then(function(user) {
            req.session.userId = user.id;

            // Add this :
            req.session.save(function() {             
                return res.redirect('makeitem');
            });

        });
    } else {
        var err = new Error('All fields required.');
        err.status = 400;
        err.message = 'All fields required.';
        console.log(err.message);
        res.send(err.message);
    }

});
```